# Import Text file into MySQL WorkBench. Syntax Error

Tags: mysql, workbench, bigdata

First of all I'm kind of beginner working with MySQL sorry if my question is not really relevant, but I have been struggling all the day and I couldn't solve it.

I want to import a text file into MySQL table test1 but I have the following problem:
    **SYNTAX ERROR INFILE (infile) is not valid input at this position**

In the image below you can see the line I wrote to import the file and how it appears INFILE in red showing the error.

[image]

This is the comand I used to create test1:

```
CREATE TABLE test1 (
  ID int(4),
  HOUR int(6),
  WASTE int(4)
  )
```

Do you know what could happen?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Do you have anything immediately preceding the `LOAD DATA` line?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. No, I don´t have anything preceding the line of LOAD DATA. Is the first line of the script. I am also wondering if there´s other way to import a text file via WorkBench into MySQL data base

Comment: Have you read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-admin-export-import-table.html ?

Comment: Thanks a lot! Seems that can export just JSON or CSV files but no Text files (which is a bit weird). But may I can try to trasnform the Text file into a CSV and try that way. I´ll let you know if it works. I cannot use Excel because I have more than 2 million of rows so it the excel cut me the data.

Answer (score 0):

To solve the error you have to add LOCAL and write the path with double bars like this:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'H:\\My Documents\\Folder1\\File1.txt' INTO TABLE test1;
```